# Stripe Payment Keyboard Automatically Popping Open

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

I'm working on an iOS app that uses Stripe's payment system. The problem is, the code I have below causes the stripe's keyboard for credit card information entry to automatically open:

```
// PaymentViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  PTKView *view = [[PTKView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,20,290,55)];
  self.paymentView = view;
  self.paymentView.delegate = self;
  [self.view addSubview:self.paymentView];
}
```

But I want the keyboard to be displayed after the user selects the PTKView (the grey bar like thing provided by Stripe) Right now, as soon as the view loads, the keyboard to enter credit card details is already open but I only want the bar to appear, so the user can tap that to open the keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have to stop the keyboard apperance, go to the PTKView.m fie there is one function "*stateCardNumber*" and comment the code,

```
[self.cardNumberField becomeFirstResponder];
```

that will stop the automatic keyboard open.

Comment: That does it, but how do I make it to go away when the user taps another part of the screen?

Comment: You have added this view as a SubView, so you need to remove it from that view. You can show the button or use gesture recognizer to remove the view.

Answer (score 0):

In ViewWillAppear: Find the current first responder by using below mentioned category over UIResponder and resignFirstResponder.

```
    @interface UIResponder (FirstResponder)
+(id)currentFirstResponder ;
-(NSString*) firstRespondersViewController;
@end

@implementation UIResponder (FirstResponder)
static __weak id currentFirstResponder;

+(id)currentFirstResponder {
    currentFirstResponder = nil;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(findFirstResponder:) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
    return currentFirstResponder;
}

-(void)findFirstResponder:(id)sender {
    currentFirstResponder = self;
}

-(NSString*) firstRespondersViewController{
    UIResponder *responder = self; \
    while ([responder isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) \
        responder = [responder nextResponder]; \
    (UIViewController *)responder;
    NSLog(@"class is %@", NSStringFromClass([responder class]));
    return NSStringFromClass([responder class]);
}
@end
```

Hope this helps.